# Weblogic JMS with SSL in Mulesoft

Tags: java, jms, mule, weblogic12c, mule-esb

How to correctly configure the required connection factory spring bean for the Mulesoft JMS connector (SSL WebLogic)?

Following: 
https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-enable-SSL-in-Apache-Active-MQ 
[WebMQ with SSL in Mulesoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935332/webmq-with-ssl-in-mulesoft)

And Oracle's documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/JMSPG/implement.htm

I still have not clear what properties or what class to use (weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory or weblogic.jms.XAConnectionFactory), and I haven't found any documentation that is specifically about Mulesoft, Weblogic JMS and SSL

e.g. WebsphereMQ

```
<spring:beans>
  <spring:bean id="WebSphereMQConnectionFactory"class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory";;>
    <spring:property name="hostName"value="your_hostname"/>
    <spring:property name="port"value="your_port"/>
    <spring:property name="queueManager"value="your_queue_manager"/>
    <spring:property name="transportType"value="1"/>
    <spring:property name="targetClientMatching"value="true"/>
    <spring:property name="sSLCipherSuite"value="your_matching_ssl_cipher_suite"/>
  </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

WebLogic 12.1.2 (JMS) 
Muleruntime 3.9.0 (Hybrid)